# pouchDB database locking up - unable to begin transaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, pouchdb, web-sql

I have the following service that starts a pouchDB database.

```
.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", "$cordovaNetwork", function($rootScope, $q, $cordovaNetwork) {

  var self = this;

  self.db = new PouchDB(localStorage['uid'], {auto_compaction: true});

  ////////
  ////////

  self.findUser = function(idnum) {
    return $q.when(self.db.query('filters/users'))
    .then(function(resp) {
      var found = false, found_id;
      angular.forEach(resp.rows, function(u, id) { if(u.value == idnum) { found = true; found_id = u.id; } });
      if(found) return found_id; else return false;
    })
    .catch(function(resp) { console.log(JSON.stringify(resp)); return null; })
  }

  self.get = function(id, attachment_bool) { 
    return $q.when(self.db.get(id, {attachments:attachment_bool}))
    .then(function(data) { 
        return data; 
    }); 
  }


}])
```

Somehow, my database got locked and I am receiving the following error when I do the `findUser` function in my controller:

**ERROR**

```
{  
  "status":500,
  "name":"web_sql_went_bad",
  "message":"unknown",
  "error":true,
  "reason":"unable to begin transaction (5 database is locked)"
}
```

Here is my code. I'm really confused because this has worked before and have had no issues. What's really interesting is my `get()` function gives no errors when communication with the database.

Does anyone know why this might happen and what I can do to either restart the database or dive deeper into the problem so this doesn't happen again?

**CODE**

```
.controller('document', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $cordovaNetwork, $cordovaDialogs, $q, $pouchDB) {

   //THIS GIVES ME ERROR
   $q.when($pouchDB.findUser($rootScope.id)).then(function(user){
     console.log('HI');
    });

   //NO ERROR
   $q.when($pouchDB.get($stateParams.template_id, true))
   .then(function(data) {
     console.log("hello");
   });
```

**IT SHOULD BE NOTED** that when I restart my application, my code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @Flimzy I am emulating iOS

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6324) might be of interest for you...

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? We're getting this error rather frequently as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Nope couldn't figure it out. I just got off of Cordova and onto react native and haven't had the issue since

Comment: @bryan What do you use for offline persistence then? Still pouchdb? We're having this issue crop up consistently (in Ionic 3), and have been 100% unsuccessful thus far in tracking it down

Comment: @Jonathan still using pouchdb via react-native using the devices local storage thankfully